# Getting an int's ASCII code

Tags: java, byte

Is there any "cleaner" way to do the following?

```
byte b;
int chLen = /*for example*/ (int)(Math.random() * 10);
b = ("" + (int)(char)chLen).getBytes()[0];
```

This, essentially, takes an int that is >= 0 and < 10 and gets its ASCII code and stores it into a byte, but it looks like there is a better method. Any ideas???

Comment: To test this you can use
`System.out.println(chLen);
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println((char)b);`
and the first and last output should be the same while the middle input should be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like `n + '0'`, where n is an `int` between 0 and 9?

Comment: Or for that matter, `n | '0'`. Since the ASCII codes for '0' through '9' are 0x30 through 0x39, you don't need to carry. (Not that this will save you any cycles in most modern machines.) ((Typo corrected.))

Comment: Yup! Thank you. Quick question, though. What? '0' is `null` (in terms of char), right? So, how does adding null char change the int...?

Comment: @dylnmc While the byte *value* `0` is typically used as a null string terminator in many programming languages, don't confuse that with the zero *character* `'0'` (note the single quotes mark this as a character), which when encoded in ASCII is the decimal value 48 (or hex value 0x30).

Comment: @dylnmc `'\0'` is not `'0'`

Comment: Oh... gotcha! Silly me; so '0' basically (when typecast to an int or byte) gets converted to the ASCII code -- the decimal representation of a char -- and '0' (whose decimal ASCII code is 48) is the first on the list, so an `int n` (let's say `n = 1`) is added to 48 to get the ASCII code 49 which does, in fact, represent '1'. Right... or left?

Answer (score 0):

How about below:

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(chLen).array();

for (byte b : bytes) {
   System.out.format("0x%x ", b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a random number from 0 to 9 and then add it to '0', I'd use [`Random.nextInt(10)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) to get such a number,

```
Random rand = new Random();
int ch = '0' + rand.nextInt(10);
System.out.printf("'%s' = %d (dec), %s (hex)%n",
    String.valueOf((char) ch), ch,
    Integer.toHexString(ch));
```

Since it's difficult to debug random code, I also wrote a simple unit test,

```
for (int ch = '0'; ch <= '9'; ch++) {
  System.out.printf("'%s' = %d (dec), %s (hex)%n",
      String.valueOf((char) ch), ch,
      Integer.toHexString(ch));
}
```

Output is

```
'0' = 48 (dec), 30 (hex)
'1' = 49 (dec), 31 (hex)
'2' = 50 (dec), 32 (hex)
'3' = 51 (dec), 33 (hex)
'4' = 52 (dec), 34 (hex)
'5' = 53 (dec), 35 (hex)
'6' = 54 (dec), 36 (hex)
'7' = 55 (dec), 37 (hex)
'8' = 56 (dec), 38 (hex)
'9' = 57 (dec), 39 (hex)
```

Comment: :P I didn't know you could use `printf()` with with Java. I thought that was a C-thing... even though Java is based off C, I've still never seen `printf(String s, Object args)` in Java like in C. Also, isn't `(int)(Math.random() * 10)` the same *exact* thing as `Random rand = new Random(); rand.nextInt(10);` I've always used `min + (int)(Math.random() + (max - min + 1));` but I guess it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: @dylnmc Java added formatted printf (and String.format) in version (1.)5; As for using the Object instead of the static method, well - I suppose that is a matter of preference.